# Is it possible to access a MYSQL database table from a sharepoint hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sql

I'm alittle confused, when I google this all i seem to find is how to connect to sharepoint using a cloud hosted app hosted in windows azure, that's not what I'm looking for.

I've been creating Java applications that communicate with a MYSQL database, and now I want sharepoint to communicate with one of them.

What is the simplest way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your specific requirements, the easiest way is probably to use [BCS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661740.aspx) to create [external content types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163139.aspx) that link to your MySQL data. Your SharePoint hosted app can then read/write that data more or less as if it was a standard SharePoint list.

The benefit of this approach is that it is quite quick and easy to set up. The downside is that it may be harder to implement complex business logic.

Comment: Doesn't this apply to Sharepoint Server only? or can I do this in Sharepoint Online?

Comment: You can do it from SharePoint Online too. You just need to consider how to allow SharePoint Online connect to your database.

Answer (score 2):

Has nothing to do with SharePoint.

If you configure the server your MYSQL database runs on to accept [Cross Origin requests](http://enable-cors.org/server.html) you can access it from any environment.

A https connection is preferred, but not required when you manually instruct your browser to [allow mixed content](http://du.screenstepslive.com/s/docs/m/7107/l/219447-allow-mixed-content-in-browsers).

A REST middle-tier like [ArrestDB](https://github.com/ilausuch/ArrestDB) in your stack simplifies access.

You are communicating from the trusted Inside (SharePoint) to the Outside; you can do anything you want. (I use this a lot to keep SharePoint Lists in sync with a public MySQL database which serve public websites)

From the cruel Outside world **into** SharePoint is a whole different ballgame which requires [ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js)

## Update

From the outside PHP world into Office365/SharePoint world there now is:
https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO

Comment: I want to be able to read the data from the database, just like from a sharepoint list for example. I didn't understand much of what you wrote, as I'm pretty new (1y) to programming overall, could you be more specific of what I need to look into & studie to be able to learn how to do this?